# scipy.interpolate.SmoothSphereBivariateSpline isn't behaving as expected on example data

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation

I'm trying to interpolate a set of non-uniform data on a sphere using `scipy.interpolate.SmoothSphereBivariateSpline`. In the example in the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.SmoothSphereBivariateSpline.html), the example data is set up differently from my data, and below is a test data set that has the shape I need (`theta`, `phi`, and `z` are each 1D arrays). I've played around with changing `z` a bit, and in every case, the interpolation doesn't do a satisfactory job. Any idea what I'm doing wrong, or a better way to do what I need?

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import SmoothSphereBivariateSpline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

theta = np.array([0, 0.5, 1., 1.5, 2., 2.5, 3.])
phi = np.array([1., 2., 3., 3.5, 4., 5., 6.])
z = np.array([1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1])

lut = SmoothSphereBivariateSpline(theta,phi,z, s=len(theta))

theta_new = np.linspace(0,np.pi,50)
phi_new = np.linspace(0,2.*np.pi,50)

znew = lut(theta_new,phi_new)

theta_new_mesh, phi_new_mesh = np.meshgrid(theta_new, phi_new)

fig=plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111,projection='mollweide')
im = ax.pcolormesh(phi_new_mesh-np.pi,theta_new_mesh-np.pi/2.,znew,vmin=0, vmax=1)
ax.scatter(phi-np.pi,theta-np.pi/2.,c=z, ec='k',vmin=0,vmax=1)
```

[This is what I get when plotting `znew`, and it looks like it's doing a horrible job fitting to the data. What am I doing wrong?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yirrw.png)